# Get translation from another model in Entity in CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am following this example https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/quickstart.html#creating-the-finder-method to learn CakePhp while trying to adapt it to my circumstances. At this point, I have a Trim model and i want to find the trims that match a certain text ( like "%text%").

The problem is : Since I need translations for the project, I have a translation model with a entry model that store all the displayable text like the trim name.

the associations :

TrimTable :

```
$this->belongsTo('translation', [
        'foreignKey' => 'name',
        'bindingKey' => 'idTranslation'
    ]);
```

TranslationTable :

```
$this->hasOne('trim', [
        'foreignKey' => 'name',
        'bindingKey' => 'idTranslation'
    ]);

$this->hasMany('entry', [
        'foreignKey' => 'idTranslation',
        'bindingKey' => 'idTranslation',
        'dependent' => 'true'
    ]);
```

EntryTable :

```
$this->belongsTo('translation', [
        'foreignKey' => 'idTranslation',
        'bindingKey' => 'idTranslation'
    ]);
```

I managed to do the findLike function and find just the trim with specific text but i can't find how to then display the text instead of the id contained in the name field.

the findLike function in TrimTable (just an example with hard coded search) :

```
public function findLike(Query $query, array $options) {
    $trims = $query->matching('Translation.Entry', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['text LIKE' => 'LD3E']);
    });
    return $trims;
}
```

This is my view name_search.ctp :

```
<h1>
 Trims named like
 <?= $this->Text->toList(h($noms)) ?>
</h1>

<section>
<?php foreach ($trims as $trim): ?>
<article>
    <!-- Use the HtmlHelper to create a link -->
    <h4><?= h($trim->name) ?></h4>
    <small><?= h($trim->idProduit) ?></small>

    <!-- Use the TextHelper to format text -->
    <?= $this->Text->autoParagraph(h($trim->description)) ?>
</article>
```

[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xci0.png)
The 447 should be LD3E. So how do I get my findLike function to return a result set with the translation in it to display?

Answer (score 1):

Matching data can be found in the `_matchingData` property, it will hold an array of entities, keyed by the names of the matched associations.

```
$trim->_matchingData['Entry']->text
```

Btw,. finders should return query objects, not results sets, ie, do not call `all()`! And most of the times you should be modifying the query passed in the arguments instead of creating a new one by calling `$this->find()`.

Also CakePHP ships with translation functionality out of the box, you might want to have a look at it, just in case you didn't knew.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Filtering by Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Using Finders to Load Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Custom Finder Methods](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Behaviors > Translate](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html)**

Comment: yea I saw the translation function but sadly i'm using an old database and can't change it. Thx!